# Create Thunderbird Extensiom to lock client

Tags: javascript, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-webextensions

I have never created any kind of extension and I would like to create one for Thunderbird that can password protect the Thunderbird client. Similar to something like Master Password+

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/master-password/

I have been reading the documentation and have learned how to create and extension but I am lost as for where to start. Could someone give me an idea of how I might implement this and what APIs I will be needing to use?

Comment: I'm not aware of any API that would permit to do so :/. Just to be sure, you are aware that setting a master password in Thunderbird now prevents the client from opening until the password has been provided? (I understand this is not as flexible as the add-on you cite, I mention it just in case.)

Comment: I was not aware of the config edit that I could do to stop it displaying emails, which will do for my purpose but I can't get it not to open the client window.

Comment: What version of Thunderbird are you running? I'm on v78, and the client window never opens before I've typed the master password. (Running on Linux, but I'd expect this behaviour to be consistent across platforms?)

Comment: I was on Mint 19.1 now on 20 which comes with v68

Comment: I think that I've observed it only from v78.